# How to generate an image, including a hyperlink image map, from HTML?

Tags: c#, html, .net, image, imagemap

I have a simple web page that's dynamically created using pure HTML5 and a CSS stylesheet.  I want to convert this page to an image (preferably `.png` and `.gif`) in C#.  Here's the kicker: The image has to have an image map generated with it so the hyperlinks continue to work when someone clicks on the generated image.  I've found plenty of .NET C# libraries to convert HTML into an image, but have found none that will also generate a hyperlink image map.

Does anyone know how to generate images with hyperlink image maps from HTML in C#?  I'm thinking I may need to code this from scratch using a WebBrowser control, then creating an image map based on pixel placement of the hyperlinks.

Cheers!

Comment: Asking for help finding a tutorial or product that fulfills your needs is typically off topic for SO.  Instead, you may want to ask how to go about doing that yourself with example code of what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realize I came across as asking for an existing framework/library.  I know full well I'll have to code this by hand, most likely using a WebBrowser control to generate the image, then carefully create an image map for the hyperlinks.  But before I do - I just want to know if anyone has done it themselves?  I've updated the question to clarify.  Thanks, Erik.  :)